# Question about aneuploidy

Tags: genetics, chromosome

I am learning about aneuploidy and non-disjunction and just wanted some clarification with regards to terminology. In particular, do the terms monosimony and trisimony refer only to INDIVIDUALS (i.e. a non-disjuction event during meisosi would produce some gametes with an extra chromosome and some lacking a chromosome, however we do not refer to the gametes as having/being monosimotic (?)/monosimony; we only talk about the zygotes and individuals formed from fertilisation involving these faulty gametes as having monosimony/trisimony etc)

Or do we refer to gametes as having monosimony or trisomny also?

Comment: Are you asking what the terminology is for a gamete that is missing a chromosome (leading to monosomy) and one that has two of a chromosome (leading to trisomy when it fuses)?

Comment: @KoenvdH yes. I am confused as to whether the terms trisimony and monosimony can refer to gametes as well.